# Dynamic call to native library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am trying to invoke function from native c++ dll, given by name, arguments and return type.
Now i having problem to make delegate for Marshalling.

I am doing this:

```
Object^ Invike(Type^ Return_Type, array<Type^>^ Types, array<Object^>^ Parameters)
{
 //demo data
 Return_Type=long::typeid;
 Types = gcnew array < Type^ > {String::typeid, int::typeid};
 Parameters = gcnew array < Type^ > {"test",1};

 //parameters initializated in class constructor
 //IntPtr DLL_File = Native_Dll::LoadLibrary(Dll_Name);
 //IntPtr Init_Function = Native_Dll::GetProcAddress(DLL_File, "_McamGetNumberofCameras@0");

 DynamicMethod^ Function_Prototype = gcnew DynamicMethod("test", Return_Type, Types);

 //ArgumentException exception in this line
 Delegate^ Function_Delegate = Marshal::GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(Init_Function, Function_Prototype->GetType());

 Object^ Result = Function_Delegate->DynamicInvoke(Parameters);

 return Result;
}
```

At line with creating Function_Delegate i have an exception

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Type must derive from Delegate.
```

It is possible to do what i want?

Is any other ways to do this?

I am looking to Func<> template also, but not really understand how to use it.

Comment: That's not possible, GetDelegateForFunctionPointer() does not support generic delegates.  You'll have to declare the delegate types explicitly.  That's pretty painful of course.  As long as you are using LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress, you're much better off declaring the exported functions with [DllImport] instead.  The pinvoke marshaller gives you everything for free, including the DynamicMethod plumbing you are trying to write.

Comment: @Hans Passant by saying "pinvoke marshaller" you mean [DllImport]? Like here [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static IntPtr LoadLibrary(String^ DLL_Name); and i can use LoadLibrary("Name") in code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem, by making dynamic wrapper using AssemblyBuilder.
Here is code piece.

```
AssemblyName^ Delegate_Class_Name = gcnew AssemblyName("Dynamic_Class");

AssemblyBuilder^ Delegate_Class = AppDomain::CurrentDomain->DefineDynamicAssembly(Delegate_Class_Name, AssemblyBuilderAccess::RunAndSave);

ModuleBuilder^ Delegate_Class_Module = Delegate_Class->DefineDynamicModule(Delegate_Class_Name->Name, Delegate_Class_Name->Name + ".dll");

TypeBuilder^ Delegate_Class_Type = Delegate_Class_Module->DefineType("Dynamic_Class_Type", TypeAttributes::Public);

//a can add as much functions from native dll as a need
MethodBuilder^ Delegate_Function = Delegate_Class_Type->DefinePInvokeMethod(
        "_McamGetNumberofCameras@0",
        Dll_Name,
        MethodAttributes::Public | MethodAttributes::Static | MethodAttributes::PinvokeImpl,
        CallingConventions::Standard,
        long::typeid,
        Type::EmptyTypes,
        CallingConvention::Winapi,
        CharSet::Ansi);

Delegate_Function->SetImplementationFlags(Delegate_Function->GetMethodImplementationFlags() | MethodImplAttributes::PreserveSig);

Type^ Delegate_Type = Delegate_Class_Type->CreateType();

MethodInfo^ Delegate_Instace = Delegate_Type->GetMethod("_McamGetNumberofCameras@0");

//now i can just run it.
int result= (int) Delegate_Instace->Invoke(nullptr, nullptr);
```